# Husky hook post-merge checking if any changes on package.json and execute npm install if detected changes

Tags: git, git-husky

I want to the hook to do something like run NPM install after merge branch but only if package.json file is being modified

I'm not sure if I'm doing it correctly, please find my post-merge below

```sh
#!/bin/sh
. "$(dirname "$0")/_/husky.sh"

differenceCode=$git diff HEAD^ HEAD --exit-code -- ./package.json

echo "test - $?"

if [ "$?" != 0 ]; then 
npm install
fi
```

I can run `git diff HEAD^ HEAD --exit-code -- ./package.json` from bash and also `echo $?` show me 1 when there are changes in `package.json` else it return me 0.

However when I included that command in the post-merge file, and trigger the post-merge event it show me:

```
diff: unknown option -- exit-code
diff: Try 'diff --help' for more information.
husky - post-merge hook exited with code 2 (error)
```

Anyone can help me with this please.

Comment: Here's a great article I found while researching this: https://jshakespeare.com/use-git-hooks-and-husky-to-tell-your-teammates-when-to-run-npm-install/

Answer (score 3):

You wrote:

```
differenceCode=$git diff HEAD^ HEAD --exit-code -- ./package.json
```

in your script.  (Why did you put a dollar sign `$` in front of `git`?)

This is the immediate source of your problem.  `$git` is an unset variable; in `sh`, unset variables expand to nothing; so you are running the command:

```
diff HEAD^ HEAD --exit-code -- ./package.json
```

and not the command:

```
git diff HEAD^ HEAD --exit-code -- ./package.json
```

If you remove the stray `$` sign, that problem will go away.

Your subsequent:

```
echo "test - $?"
```

will show the exit code from the command you ran, if it gets executed.  The fact that it *doesn't* get executed indicates that the line:

```
. "$(dirname "$0")/_/husky.sh"
```

must have set the `-e` option ("exit on error").  If it did that, you don't need a subsequent test.  But there is another error here:

```
echo "test - $?"

if [ "$?" != 0 ]; then 
npm install
fi
```

You would need to *remove* the `echo` command, because `echo` itself *is* a command, and as such, it *sets* the `$?` last-command exit status variable.  So if `echo` succeeds—it almost always does—it will set `$?` to zero.

If `-e` is set, as it appears to be, we won't get this far if `$?` is *not* zero.  Since `-e` is set, it's important *not* to allow the `git diff` command to cause the script to exit early.  To fix that, replace the whole sequence with:

```
if git diff HEAD^ HEAD --exit-code -- ./package.json; then
    # ... code to handle a zero exit code here
else
    # ... code to handle a nonzero exit here
fi
```

The test will now work even with `-e` set.

You can simplify this a bit since you have nothing to do in the `then` section by writing:

```
if ! git diff HEAD^ HEAD --exit-code -- ./package.json; then
    npm install
fi
```

and once you do that, you can simplify this one more step by writing:

```
git diff HEAD^ HEAD --exit-code -- ./package.json || npm install
```

but the main things to do are:

1. remove the `$`;
2. move the `git diff` command *into* the `if` test.

These are what's required; everything else is optional.

Comment: thanks for the reply,
I have changed the code to
`c
#!/bin/sh
. "$(dirname "$0")/_/husky.sh"
if  git diff HEAD^ HEAD --exit-code -- ./package.json; then
npm install
fi`


if I'm correct it will only run npm install if there is changes for package.json.

However I found it always run npm install even package.json doesn't have any changes.
Is there something I'm wrong or I have to add to make it work?

Comment: `if git diff ...; then list; of; commands; fi` runs the commands if the `git diff` program exits *zero*. That's why I said you need to put them in the `else` section, or use one of the fancier alternatives.